# Google Calendar API V3 Java: Unable to use 'primary' for Calendars:get

Tags: java, eclipse, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm very new to the Google Calendar V3 Java API. I'm developing in Java, using Eclipse. So far, I have succeeded in:

1. Getting the CalendarList summaries of all the different calendars inside a particular Google account
2. Getting the CalendarList summary of just one of the calendars inside a particular Google account, using the Calendar ID as an identifier.

Now, I would like to explore Calendars instead of CalendarList. I tried implementing the Calendars get method. However, I am facing a problem.

Google's tutorial states this as an example code:

```
Calendar calendar = service.calendars().get('primary').execute();
System.out.println(calendar.getSummary());
```

However, Eclipse highlights the 'primary' and says that it is an "Invalid Character Constant".

I tried changing it into a string "primary" instead, and Eclipse highlights the entire line, saying that there is a type mismatch.

I am very unsure what is really expected from the 'primary' array of strings given in Google's tutorial. Am I supposed to replace it with the calendar ID of the primary calendar? I tried that, both as a string and as an array of characters, but I keep on getting compilation errors from Eclipse.

Here is my code used:

```
public static void getCalendarSummary(String calendarID, Calendar service) throws IOException{ 
    Calendar calendar = service.calendars().get("primary").execute();
    System.out.println(calendar.getSummary());
}
```

Would anyone be able to enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong? I have searched all over the Google tutorial references, but failed to come to a conclusion. Thank you.

This is the link to Google's tutorial: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get?hl=fr

Edit:
After running the program, this is what I get. The first two methods work fine and deliver the right results. However, I get an error for the method in question - unresolved compilation problem - invalid character constant. Here's the entire response:

```
Go to the following address:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=369332843116-gr8ct1guerlf1fudpgivfjv43h0oleip.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
What is the 'code' url parameter?
4/LvuhiV9Qb_gzCgXmkveIw2kfbOFA.gtXwZ0hWA0QRcp7tdiljKKa1LV4tkQI
GooCal
ID: quolc4s8etou3ea1ca071ud9tk@group.calendar.google.com
Summary: DEADLINES
ID: u8jsu7vcrbh9okbj4tbs1nev74@group.calendar.google.com
Summary: Calendar 1
ID: gfof3i5u8pdn3esjk3mbmgiop8@group.calendar.google.com
Summary: LightUp
ID: i.*****@gmail.com
Summary: Personal Events
ID: w*****@gmail.com
Summary: w*****@gmail.com
ID: horiq2vgch2cprklf58ntdvhd8@group.calendar.google.com
Summary: Team A********** - Orbital Project
ID: 2h4du2sgsu1t5p2238j2mbk77k@group.calendar.google.com
Summary: TechTouch - GG Fix
ID: i357fqqhffrf1fa9udcbn9sikc@group.calendar.google.com
Summary: GooCal
ID: en.singapore#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com
Summary: Holidays in Singapore
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Invalid character constant

    at SimpleCalendarTest.getCalendarSummary(SimpleCalendarTest.java:100)
    at SimpleCalendarTest.main(SimpleCalendarTest.java:81)
```

Here is my entire code, if it will help. :)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.CalendarList;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.CalendarListEntry;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.*;


public class SimpleCalendarTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //Two globals that will be used in each step.
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        //Create the authorization code flow manager
        Set<String> scope = Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
        String clientId = "xxxxxxx";
        String clientSecret = "xxxxxxx";

        //Use a factory pattern to create the code flow
        AuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder codeFlowBuilder = 
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        httpTransport, 
                        jsonFactory, 
                        clientId, 
                        clientSecret, 
                        scope
                );
        AuthorizationCodeFlow codeFlow = codeFlowBuilder.build();

        //set the code flow to use a dummy user
        //in a servlet, this could be the session id
        String userId = "ipeech";

        //"redirect" to the authentication url
        String redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
        AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorizationUrl = codeFlow.newAuthorizationUrl();
        authorizationUrl.setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
        System.out.println("Go to the following address:");
        System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

        //use the code that is returned as a url parameter
        //to request an authorization token
        System.out.println("What is the 'code' url parameter?");
        String code = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest tokenRequest = codeFlow.newTokenRequest(code);
        tokenRequest.setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
        TokenResponse tokenResponse = tokenRequest.execute();

        //Now, with the token and user id, we have credentials
        Credential credential = codeFlow.createAndStoreCredential(tokenResponse, userId);

        //Credentials may be used to initialize http requests
        HttpRequestInitializer initializer = credential;
        //and thus are used to initialize the calendar service
        Calendar.Builder serviceBuilder = new Calendar.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, initializer);
        serviceBuilder.setApplicationName("GooCal");
        Calendar calendar = serviceBuilder.build();

        //get some data
        String calendarID = "xxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com";
        getCalendarListSummary(calendarID,calendar);
        getAllCalendarListSummary(calendar);
        getCalendarSummary(calendarID,calendar);
    }

    public static void getCalendarListSummary(String calendarID, Calendar calendar) throws IOException{
        CalendarListEntry calendarListEntry = calendar.calendarList().get(calendarID).execute();
        System.out.println(calendarListEntry.getSummary());
    }

    public static void getAllCalendarListSummary (Calendar calendar) throws IOException{
        Calendar.CalendarList.List listRequest = calendar.calendarList().list();
        CalendarList feed = listRequest.execute();
        for(CalendarListEntry entry:feed.getItems()){
            System.out.println("ID: " + entry.getId());
            System.out.println("Summary: " + entry.getSummary());
        }
    }


    public static void getCalendarSummary(String calendarID, Calendar service) throws IOException{ 
        Calendar calendar = service.calendars().get('primary').execute();
        System.out.println(calendar.getSummary());
    }
}
```

Thanks! :)

Edit 2: When I replace 'primary' with "primary", this is the error message I get.

```
What is the 'code' url parameter?
    4/LvuhiV9Qb_gzCgXmkveIw2kfbOFA.gtXwZ0hWA0QRcp7tdiljKKa1LV4tkQI
    GooCal
    ID: quolc4s8etou3ea1ca071ud9tk@group.calendar.google.com
    Summary: DEADLINES
    ID: u8jsu7vcrbh9okbj4tbs1nev74@group.calendar.google.com
    Summary: Calendar 1
    ID: gfof3i5u8pdn3esjk3mbmgiop8@group.calendar.google.com
    Summary: LightUp
    ID: i.*****@gmail.com
    Summary: Personal Events
    ID: w*****@gmail.com
    Summary: w*****@gmail.com
    ID: horiq2vgch2cprklf58ntdvhd8@group.calendar.google.com
    Summary: Team A********** - Orbital Project
    ID: 2h4du2sgsu1t5p2238j2mbk77k@group.calendar.google.com
    Summary: TechTouch - GG Fix
    ID: i357fqqhffrf1fa9udcbn9sikc@group.calendar.google.com
    Summary: GooCal
    ID: en.singapore#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com
    Summary: Holidays in Singapore
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar to com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar
    The method getSummary() is undefined for the type Calendar

    at SimpleCalendarTest.getCalendarSummary(SimpleCalendarTest.java:100)
    at SimpleCalendarTest.main(SimpleCalendarTest.java:81)
```

It appears that there is a type mismatch. Thanks for your help!

Edit 3: Replacing import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar with com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar causes other problems. Eclipse highlights that the code used to initialize the calendar service has a problem. Calendar.Builder cannot be resolved as a type.

```
Calendar.Builder serviceBuilder = new Calendar.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, initializer);
```

When I run, I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Calendar.Builder cannot be resolved to a type
    Calendar.Builder cannot be resolved to a type

    at SimpleCalendarTest.main(SimpleCalendarTest.java:73)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code seems legit, please share the message that eclipse is giving you.

Comment: I have edited the code to include the message that eclipse is giving me, as well as added the full code I have been using. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool, please replace the single quotes in 'primary' with apostrophes "primary" and paste the error message you get then. This one is certainly wrong as you can only use single quotes for characters, not for strings in Java.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the message that eclipse is giving me when I replace 'primary' with "primary". There is a type mismatch. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar with com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar.

Comment: When I do that, my current calendar initializer seems to have stopped working. I have edited my original post to show the errors I get when I replace the import statement. Thanks for your help!

Comment: let's make it this then: com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar calendar = service.calendars().get("primary").execute();

Comment: That works! Thank you so much for taking your time to help me, luc. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use double quotes instead of single quotes around "primary" :) Single quotes are for chars, like 'a' in Java.
2. Read the error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar to com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar". These are two absolutely different classes (note the package names), "Calendar" is just part of class name.