# Need help on Google API Calendar V3 Java and OAUTH2

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

i'm trying to handle my Google Agenda by using the Google Calendar APi V3( Java ).
However, i'm quite new to this and to OAUTH2 .. then i've searched for examples and i found one here :
[Google Calendar API V3 Java: Unable to use 'primary' for Calendars:get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951985/google-calendar-api-v3-java-unable-to-use-primary-for-calendarsget)
Here is the code :

```
   import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.auth.helpers.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.CalendarList;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.CalendarListEntry;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //Two globals that will be used in each step.
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    //Create the authorization code flow manager
    Set<String> scope = Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
    String clientId = "xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    String clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    //Use a factory pattern to create the code flow
    AuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder codeFlowBuilder = 
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    httpTransport, 
                    jsonFactory, 
                    clientId, 
                    clientSecret, 
                    scope
            );
    AuthorizationCodeFlow codeFlow = codeFlowBuilder.build();

    //set the code flow to use a dummy user
    //in a servlet, this could be the session id
    String userId = "ipeech";

    //"redirect" to the authentication url
    String redirectUri = "https://www.example.com/oauth2callback";
    AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorizationUrl = codeFlow.newAuthorizationUrl();
    authorizationUrl.setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
    System.out.println("Go to the following address:");
    System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

    //use the code that is returned as a url parameter
    //to request an authorization token
    System.out.println("What is the 'code' url parameter?");
   String code = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest tokenRequest = codeFlow.newTokenRequest(code);
    tokenRequest.setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
    TokenResponse tokenResponse = tokenRequest.execute();

    //Now, with the token and user id, we have credentials
    com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential credential = codeFlow.createAndStoreCredential(tokenResponse, userId);

    //Credentials may be used to initialize http requests
    HttpRequestInitializer initializer = credential;
    //and thus are used to initialize the calendar service
    Calendar.Builder serviceBuilder = new Calendar.Builder(
            httpTransport, jsonFactory, initializer);
    serviceBuilder.setApplicationName("Example");
    Calendar calendar = serviceBuilder.build();

    //get some data

    String calendarID = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    getCalendarListSummary(calendarID,calendar);
    getAllCalendarListSummary(calendar);
    //getCalendarSummary(calendarID,calendar);
}

public static void getCalendarListSummary(String calendarID, Calendar calendar) throws IOException{
    CalendarListEntry calendarListEntry = calendar.calendarList().get(calendarID).execute();
    System.out.println(calendarListEntry.getSummary());
}

public static void getAllCalendarListSummary (Calendar calendar) throws IOException{
    Calendar.CalendarList.List listRequest = calendar.calendarList().list();
    com.google.api.services.calendar.model.CalendarList feed = listRequest.execute();
    for(CalendarListEntry entry:feed.getItems()){
        System.out.println("ID: " + entry.getId());
        System.out.println("Summary: " + entry.getSummary());
    }
}
```

When i launch the programm, it asks me to give the authorization code ("What is the 'code' url parameter?") but i don't know where to find it .. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, there is a part that says "Go to the following address:" you have to copy that url, paste it in the browser and then you will receive the authorization code.  Copy that code and paste it after "What is the 'code' url parameter?" and press "Enter" so the program can continue.

This is a basic example and that why the OAuth 2 flow is done that way.

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/cmdline/CalendarSample.java?repo=samples) is a complete example of a Google calendar java program. I would suggest to first understand how [OAuth 2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) works, how to create projects in the [Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) and how to create credentials for those projects. Then it would be easier to understand and use the complete example.

Comment: Hi Gerardo,  i've understood what you say but it looks like the url given by google does not contain the wanted 'code' : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/oauth2callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar . I've already created a project in the Developer console and followed the instructions,i've also downloaded the json file linked to my google agenda..

Comment: did you change the clientID and clientSecret in your test code with your project clientID and clientSecret?

Comment: I've just ckecked and yes, it has been done ..do you know to what does the String userId is for ? maybe it's where the problem come from .. i haven't change it from the code i've used .. the response the console gave  me looks like :https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id-xxxxxx   &redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/oauth2callback &response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar . thanks for your help

Comment: use this redirect uri urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: i've tried using urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob and urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto but the issue is still the same : the response given by the console is the same excepting the part "redirected url" replaced by the url i've just put instead of: example.com/oauth2callback ..

Comment: Did you create a installed application credentials? In the developer console of your project, in the section APIs & OAuth -> Consent Screen  did you filled the necessary fields (app name, email ..etc) ?

Comment: thanks ! I've checked it and i've noticed that i choose "Web application" instead of "Installed application", then i changed it and edited new keys and ids for my app.i've updated my code, downloaded the new JSON File key and put it in the folder which contains my project, but unfortunately, it doesn't work and the issue is still the same ...In the Developer Console, there's a way to check how many url requests have been sent to your project, but it's empty, even after having received a useless authorization url ..

Comment: I don't understand how does the author of the code i've used have found the authorization code, because the one he wrote wasn't in the console response ...same as me but i don't know where to find it ...

Comment: Did you also configured the "Content Screen"? using the url you posted: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/oauth2callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
I changed the client id for my own and the redirect_uri for: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob and i was able to get the access token in the browser but only after i configured the content ascreen of the project in the developer console

Comment: You mean pasting the url i got with my programm in twice URL parameters in consent screen ? if yes, i"ve just tried and it has failed .. where did you get the access token? "in the browser" ? i'm afraid i've made you lose a lot of time for nothing : i think i just don't have understood where to find this famous authorization code .. because i'm looking for it in my console .. thanks to be so patient with me !

Comment: So, in the developers console go to "APIs & OAuth -> Consent Screen" there you have to provide a name for your app and an email. after doing that, run the code you posted (with correct client id, client secret and redirect uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob) in the console your program will show you a url, you have to copy and paste it in the browser... then you have to authorize the app and then you will receive the access token in the browse .. copy that code and paste it in the console, no worries i know it can be frustrating at the beginning

Comment: well.. i understand better now, i've tried to do what you said, but Google told me that there was an error,an "invalid request" .. i have a doubt, in the google console, there's two kind of clientId provided :one for the service acount and another one for the "native application", i obviously choose the second one and downloaded the 2nd json file, was it right ? i'm reconsidering the fact to use this API, because my goal is to handle it from an android application, but as i didn't know how to do, i've tried first on my computer ..

Comment: you can probably check this tutorial for android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html